# IOS- UIScrollview swipe gesture in objective-C similar to snapchat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

**What I have achieved so far?**

1) I can swipe between view controllers(View1 and View 2) as showing in the image below

2) I Created a button in View1 That will allow me to go to View2 by pressing the button.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAV2M.png)

**What I want To achieve Next ?**

1)  To make A Loop Swipe between these Two view controllers(View1 and View 2) by swiping from View1 to View2 and from View2 to View1.

2) After pressing the button in View1, it will take me to View2, After that i can't swipe anymore.

**Thank you for your interest in this question.I would appreciate your help**

Here's My Code for the ScrollViewController.m

```
#import "ScrollViewController.h"
#import "View1.h"
#import "View2.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    View1 * V1 = [[View1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
    View2 * V2 = [[View2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];



    [self addChildViewController:V1];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:V1.view];
    [V1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];


    [self addChildViewController:V2];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:V2.view];
    [V2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    CGRect V2Frame = V2.view.frame;
    V2Frame.origin.x= self.view.frame.size.width;
    V2.view.frame = V2Frame;

    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here's My code for View1.m

```
#import "View1.h"
#import "View2.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface View1 ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;

@end

@implementation View1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {


    View2 * V2 = [[View2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:V2 animated:NO completion:NULL];


}
```

Here's My code For View2.m

```
#import "View2.h"
#import "View1.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface View2 ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;

@end

@implementation View2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.




//self.ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: I don't see a UIGestureRecognizer in your code.  In order to swipe you need something to recognize a swipe gesture occurred and then to execute some code.